# How to mutiply 2 tensors of different shapes using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have 2 tensors a and b. I want to obtain the product of a and b as ([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]). But a has 5 values per tensor element and b has 4. what is the right approach to multiply and b and obtain the desired result. I obtained an error. InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [2,4] vs. [2,5] [Op:Mul].

```
a=tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,8],[5,6,7,8,9]])
b=tf.constant([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]])
tf.multiply(b, a)
```

Comment: What's the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated in the question you want to obtain subset of the "a" tensor.

You can use [tf.slice](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/slice) for this

For example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

a=tf.constant([[1,2,3,4,8],[5,6,7,8,9]])
b=tf.constant([[1,1,1,1],[1,1,1,1]])
print(tf.slice(a, [0, 0], [2, 4]))
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[1 2 3 4]
 [5 6 7 8]], shape=(2, 4), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I used the slice. I thought there is an alternate and a much better way to obtain the result